# HTML Drag a div inside another div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a div (green div) which can be dragged around but within the boundaries of another div (small div with border).
This is what I have tried till now.

[click here](http://jsfiddle.net/xt25du2j/3/)

I will try to explain in figure

```
I want this
```

[image]

```
But not this
```

[image]

Green div should be able to drag around but the limit should be the small div (white space should not be seen in small div) in all four corners like the figure above.

Comment: Do you mean you want to make the green `div` smaller and draggable inside the `div` with black border?

Comment: size of both div should remain the same but green div should not be draggable beyond the border of the small div with black border.

Comment: That doesn't make any sense. Since, the size of the green `div` is bigger than the `div` with black border, the green `div` is always going to overflow.

Comment: overflow is not the problem. white space should not be seen inside the small div

Comment: Okay now I get it. You want to snap the green `div` as soon as its inside the `div` with black border, right?

Comment: You want to use `.draggable` which is part of [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement)

Comment: @chipChocolate.py yeah

Comment: @misterManSam i have use that but the div can be drag any where but i want to set the boundaries.

Comment: You can use the `containment` property. [This link](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#constrain-movement) shows an example.

Comment: @rishal, check my fiddle link in the answer if you're confused

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to use the `containment` property of the `.draggable`, here's example of how to do it

```
$(function() {
    $("#draggable").draggable({ 
        containment: [-100,-100,0,0]
    });
});
```

look for the `parameter` that's being used in the `containment`, it's the `offset` or `position` ( I forget which one ) of the area from their `relative position` where the `.draggable` will be able to be dragged, for example with this `HTML`

```
<div class="bigDiv">
    <div class="smallDiv" id="draggable">
    </div>
</div>
```

and `CSS`

```
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.bigDiv{
    border: solid 1px black;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
}

.smallDiv{
    opacity: 0.5;
    background-color: limegreen;
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    /*overflow: hidden;*/
}
```

because the `offset` of `.bigDiv` from it's `relative position` is `top: 0;` and `left: 0;`, you need to make the `containment` to this [1st_param, 2nd_param, 3rd_param, 4th_param], where

- `1st_param` is the left most `offset` from the `relative position`, so
  because the `container width` is `200px` and the `.draggable` is
  `300px`, you need to calculate it to `container width` + `container
  offset left` - `.draggable width` (200 + 0 - 300 = -100)
- `2nd param` is the top most `offset` from the `relative position`, so
  because the `container height` is `200px` and the `.draggable` is
  `300px`, you need to calculate it to `container height` + `container
  offset top` - `.draggable height` (200 + 0 - 300 = -100)
- `3rd param` is the lowest left `offset` from the `relative position` ( just add the difference between `container width` and `.draggable width` to `1st_param` )
- `4th param` is the lowest top `offset` from the `relative position` ( just add the difference between `container height` and `.draggable height` to `2nd_param` )

here's the [Demo in Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xt25du2j/1/), or if you're a little bit confused,

here's the full coded one [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xt25du2j/4/), just edit the `position`, `width`, and `height` off the `.bigDiv` and `.smallDiv` to check it out in action.

Comment: @rishal, you need to tweak the code a little bit though, because in the current one, the `border` of the container will not be included, so if you use a border of `1px` until more, you will see that much space when you drag it to the most top left, try to set the border to `10px` to see what I mean

Comment: yeah i have already seen that, i just wanted the logic now I am creating my calculations, thanks heaps. first i got confused with your formula as 200+0-300 should be -100, but you have wrote 100.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){

//if the div1 is clicked performed this code
$("#div1").mousedown(function(){

$(window).mousemove(function(event) {

 var a=event.pageX;//get the position of x
 var b= event.pageY;//get the position of y
 $("#div1").css("left",a);//change the position-left of div1 and equal it to a
 $("#div1").css("top",b);//change the position-top of div1 and equal it to b

  //if more than the container do this
   if(a>450)
   {
      $("#div1").css("left",450);
   }
   if(b>260)
   {
      $("#div1").css("top",260);
   }
   //if less than the container do this
   if(a<0)
   {
      $("#div1").css("left",0);
   }

   if(b<0)
   {
      $("#div1").css("top",0);
   }
 });

});

});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div2" style="background-color:green;width:500px;height:300px; position:absolute;">

<div id="div1" style="background-color:red;width:50px;height:40px; position:absolute;"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```